# Default model binder always creates an instance?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action that looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index(Home document) {

        return View(new BaseViewModel<Home>(document, _repository));
    }
```

but even though RouteData.Values["document"] does not exist the model binder creates an instance of Home. Is it possible to tell the model binder to give me null if the document is null?

Answer (score 2):

You might need a custom model binder if you want to change this default behavior:

```
public class MyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        // TODO: decide if you need to instantiate or not the model
        // based on the context
        if (!ShouldInstantiateModel)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(MyModelBinder))] Home document) 
{
    return View(new BaseViewModel<Home>(document, _repository));
}
```

or register it globally in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Home), new MyModelBinder());
```

Comment: In my routedata object my value is named document, is it possible to write a modelbinder that binds every model implementing a specific interface? So even if i say, public ActionResult(Home myhomepage) it would bind my myhomepage with the values from RouteData["document"] because it implements IDocumentModel?